# Math: Fields in doxygen

Tags: math, field, doxygen

does anyone know how to get symbols for the real and complex field or the projective plane with Doxygen, i.o.w symbols such as IR, IC, IP, etc. ?

I tried \f$ \field{R} \f$ for instance, but it is not recognized.

Thanks a lot for help,
G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't the standard math font commands work in Doxygen?  Things like `mathbf`, `mathcal` and `mathbb`?  Is one of those appropriate for your needs?

Comment: Hoi, I first tried \mathbb, soo, but got the same problem as with \field: ! Undefined control sequence \mathbb. Strange thing...

Comment: Try adding the line `EXTRA_PACKAGES = amsmath xr amsfonts`